# Asp net MVC - Partial view

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Опыта в mvc мало,поэтому прошу помощи.
Сайт имеет меню слева.Использовал Accordion из Bootstrap.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заголовок меню является  класс -

```
 public class Accordion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }     
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public List<AccordionContent> Contents { get; set; } = new();
      
    }
```

Пункты меню являются классом -

```
 public class AccordionContent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        
        public int AccordionId { get; set; }  
        public Accordion? Accordion { get; set; }        
     

    }
```

Код загрузки страницы -

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult RedirectCategory()
        {
            var response = _db.Accordions.Include(x => x.Contents).ToList();
            return View("Main", response);
        }
```

Как ясно из метода,что загружается Main.cshtml.
Что представляет из себя данное представление -

```
@using Learning.Entity.Entity
@model List<Accordion>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View";
    int counter = 0;
    string strCounter;

}
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">

                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    strCounter = $"targetId{counter}";
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#@strCounter" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@strCounter">
                                @item.Title
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="@strCounter" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample" style="">
                            <div class="accordion-body">
                                @foreach (var content in item.Contents)
                                {
                                    <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white"><a asp-controller="ControllerName" id="button" asp-action="ToPar" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><strong>@content.Title</strong></a></div>

                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    counter++;
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">

            <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 100%;">
                <div class="card-header">Header</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <hr class="border border-primary border-3 opacity-75">
                  @Html.Partial("_Test",Тут должна быть модель,но как мне передать то один объект,если само представление имеет лист?) @*Частичное*@
                    <hr class="border border-primary border-3 opacity-75">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как видите, представление передается `@model List<Accordion>`
Как я понял,что если я размещаю частичное в этом же представлении,то само частичное представление тоже должно принимать `@model List<Accordion>`,но мне бы хотелось передавать в частичное представление конкретный `Accordion` по Id.
Как видите,частичное представление имеет обработчик ToPar

```
 <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-dark text-white"><a asp-controller="Unity" id="button" asp-action="ToPar" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><strong>@content.Title</strong></a></div>
```

А как выглядит в контроллере -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ToPar(int id)
        {
            var response = await _db.Accordions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);   
            return PartialView("_Test", response);
        }
```

Как выглядит само частичное _Test.cshtml -

```
@using Learning.Entity.Entity
@model Accordion

    <h2>Текст частичного @Model.Title</h2>
```

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на пункт  меню слева, передавались данные в частичное представление и оно обновлялась на текущей  странице.

Вопросы:

1. Как передать в частичное представление _Test.cshtml(которое
   находится на скрине "Текст частичного") один выбранный объект из
   коллекции List так,чтобы данные внутри частичного
   представление обновились.(Upd - нашел в одном примере,что нужно в @Html.Partial("_Test",указать здесь new Accordion()).Данные загружаются ,но переходит на новую страницу,а как тогда обновить текущую?)
2. Заранее извиняюсь,но query/ajax я не
   изучал.Есть ли возможность обойтись без него?Я понимаю,что с помощью этого  можно обновлять данных не перезагружая страницу,но для обучение мне пока не столь важно.

Спасибо.

update:
Пока не решил эту задачу.Сделал так,класс на два поля:коллекция Accordion,Accordion.
Не использую частичное представление.Теперь страница перезагружается,но пока хотя бы так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вы пытаетесь по клику отрисовать что-то на странице; я бы порекомендовал использовать для этого ajax-запросы и перерисовывать страницу сразу и без обновления. Т.е., вы пишите свой контроллер, обращаетесь к нему, парсите ответ, и через js перерисовываете страницу. Более подробно - [здесь](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-in-net-core/).